# Django Rest framework nested serializer not returning relation values in validated_data

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have defined everything correctly. **(GET is working correctly)** I can get the user detail through nested serializer. But when I do **PUT** I am not getting validated_data in update method which is in UserSerializer.

**models.py**

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='users', 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)    
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    known_languages = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)     
    user_domain = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ['phone_number', 'known_languages', 'user_domain']

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    users = UserProfileSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'users']

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
        #here I am not getting users value. it is returning empty list
        return instance
```

**views.py**

```
def put(self, request, pk):

        user_obj = self.get_object(pk)
        request.POST._mutable = True
        request.data['users'] = { 'phone_number': request.data.pop('phone_number'), 'user_domain': request.data.pop('user_domain'), 'known_languages': request.data.pop('known_languages') }
        request.POST._mutable = False
        serializer = UserSerializer(user_obj, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**Can any one help on it......**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = request.data.dict()
data['users'] = { 'phone_number': request.data.pop('phone_number'), 'user_domain': request.data.pop('user_domain'), 'known_languages': request.data.pop('known_languages') }
serializer = UserSerializer(user_obj, data=data, partial=True )
```

works perfect for me

Answer (score 1):

remove this three lines:

```
request.POST._mutable = True
request.data['users'] = { 'phone_number': request.data.pop('phone_number'), 'user_domain': request.data.pop('user_domain'), 'known_languages': request.data.pop('known_languages') }
request.POST._mutable = False
```

and just use inside `update`:

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    request = self.context.get('request')
    data = request.data.copy()
    users = {
        'phone_number': data.get('phone_number'),
        'user_domain': data.get('user_domain'),
        'known_languages': data.get('known_languages')
    }
    # your code ...
```

Comment: self.context in update method is returning empty dict. Anyhow serializer should return the validated_data. But I am not getting it... Can you tell me why I am not getting it?@Bear Brown

Comment: it is because you use django class view, try to use rest api [modelviewset](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset)